# jsoup search form results parsing

Tags: jquery, parsing, http, html-parsing, jsoup

i want to get result page into doc, but i get into the doc starturl page

```
doc=Jsoup.connect(startUrl).data("search_text", search)
                            .data("charset", "utf-8")
                            .data("top-search-button", "submit")
                            .timeout(0)
                            .post();
```

the search form html:

```
<div class="b-top-search">
    <form method="post" action="http://startUrl/search/" id="globalSearch" name="globalSearch">
        <div class="b-top-search-box">
            <i class="icon top-search-spinner"></i>
            <input type="text" class="top-search-input unfocus" value="Insert search text" autocomplete="off" id="g-search-input" name="search_text" longdesc="Insert search text">
            <button class="top-search-button" type="submit"><span>Find</span></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
        </div>

        <!--Top-search-results-->
        <div class="b-top-search-results" id="g-search-result">
        <ul class="b-top-search-results__list"></ul>
        </div>
        <!--/Top-search-results-->
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes please accept it so the topic can be closed. If not please provide some feedback so I can help. If you've found the solution please provide an answer and accept it so it can be available to other users too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `data("top-search-button", "submit")` is not needed since `top-search-button` is the `class` of the element and not the `name`. It does not have a `name`, thus it doesn't expect any value. Maybe the server is expecting some metadata about the client (user-agentand referrer headers). Try this

```
doc=Jsoup.connect(startUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                           .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
                           .data("search_text", search)
                           .data("charset", "utf-8")
                           .timeout(0)
                           .post();
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved problem something like this 'doc=Jsoup.connect(startUrl+"/search/").data("search_text", search)
       .data("charset", "windows-1251")
.cookies(cookies)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36")
.referrer(starturl)
.timeout(0)
.post();'